# How can I get data after filter && sort ag-grid?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

How to get data after filter or sort in ag-grid.

I tried `api.forEachNodeAfterFilterAndSort()` but it did not call back when I applied the filter.

Any thought about this?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried and where you have been struck.

Comment: Hey `idestiny137`, its always better to share full info. But here is the example that you can look at: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/#example-get-displayed-row